# Função bitwise setBit(); em C

Tags: c, bitwise

Estou construindo uma função `setBit();` em `C` que, como o nome sugere, deve modificar um bit específico na posição `n`, de um binário `x`, com o valor `v` fornecido, que pode ser 0 ou 1.

Por se tratar de um trabalho da faculdade não é permitido usar qualquer outra coisa além dos operadores bitwise: `>>`, `<<`, `~`, `^`, `|` e `&`.

Escopo da função:

```
void set_bit(unsigned * x,
             unsigned n,
             unsigned v) {
}
```

- **Solução adotada:**

A solução adotada por mim foi de realizar um shift para a esquerda, de tamanho `n`, no valor `v`, sendo assim o valor do bit a ser inserido estaria correspondente à posição `n` desejada no número `x`. Em seguida, realizar a operação `|` pois, mesmo não solucionando todos os casos, tende a ser a solução mais efetiva.

Exemplo:

No valor `x = 0b0010` insira o valor `v = 1` na posição `n = 2`.

logo:

`v << n`, onde após o shift o valor `v` seria equivalente à `0b0100`. 
Após o `x = x | (v << n);` o número final deveria ser `x = 0b0110`.

**Código final:**

```
void set_bit(unsigned * x,
         unsigned n,
         unsigned v) {
    
  x = x | (v << n);
```

}

A pesar da lógica, em primeiro momento, parecer correta não estou conseguindo fazer a implementação pois o valor binário `x` está sendo passado na função como um `unsigned int *` e ao tentar realizar a operação `x = x | (v << n);` ele emite erro por conta disso `error: invalid operands to binary expression (‘unsigned int *’ and ‘unsigned int’)`

**Gostaria de saber:**

1. É possível realizar a alteração do bit utilizando o ponteiro `unsigned int *` como em um array?
2. Caso não seja possível realizar o acesso ao valor através do ponteiro `* x` como poderá ser realizado?
3. O operador `|` é de fato a melhor solução para o `setBit();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resposta:**

Em verificação posterior descobri que o código `x = x | (v << n);` está emitindo o erro pois, por se tratar de um ponteiro, o dado armazenado nele é um endereço de memória e por essa razão não é possível realizar as operações bitwise referenciando a variável `x`

A correção pode ser realizada através do `*x` que, dessa forma, as operações serão realizadas no valor armazenado no endereço de memória apontado por x, no entanto não é possível acessar um bit específico do dado armazenado.

Código corrigido:

```
    void set_bit(unsigned * x,
             unsigned n,
             unsigned v) {

      //Equivalente à *x = *x | (v<<n);
      *x |= v<<n;
}
```

**- A operação OR(`|`) é a melhor solução para a função proposta?**

Por mais que a operação `|` cumpra seu papel na maioria dos casos não é possível utiliza-la para setar o bit `0` quando o bit atual é `1` pois, por natureza, a operação OR sempre retornará **true (1)** caso um dos dois termos seja `1`.

**Solução:**

Como correção escolhi realizar a "limpeza" do bit a ser modificado utilizando uma operação AND(`&`) antes de realizar a modificação em si.

Foi definida uma variável auxilizar `aux`, para armazenar o valor `0b111111` de tamanho máximo 32bits, a ser utilizado para a operação AND(`&`) com `x` e em seguida subtrair o bit `1` na posição do bit que será alterado para garantir que o resultado do AND(`&`) seja `**false(0)**` e zerando o bit a ser modificado.

**Código final:**

```
void set_bit(unsigned * x,
             unsigned n,
             unsigned v) {

      //definindo o valor base de aux 
      long aux = 0b111111111111111111111111111111111;

      //Subitraindo o bit 1 na posição n a ser alterada
      aux = aux - (1<<n);

      //Zerando o bit da posição n com o AND(&)
      *x &= aux;

      //Efetuando o | para setar o bit
      *x |= v << n;
}
```